# Trying to populate a nested dictionary with .csv files within a loop in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a set of .csv spreadsheets that I would like to store in a dictionary.  I want the name of the spreadsheet to be the dictionary key, and the dictionary value to be the spreadsheet saved as a dictionary.  In the sub-dictionary, I want the column headers to be the keys and the column values to be the dictionary values, saved as floats.  My code does something, but I cannot quite figure out what exactly it is doing.

```
import os
import csv

os.chdir("pathGoesHere")
path=os.getcwd()

rivers=[]
riverDat={}
for sheet in os.listdir(path):
    if sheet.endswith(".csv"):
        temp={}
        name=sheet[0:-4]
        rivers.append(name)
        reader=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC(open(sheet))     
        for i in reader:
            key=i[0]
            temp[key]=i[1]
        print(temp)
```

[an excerpt from the top of the csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oiVu.png)

Comment: show csv file please

Comment: I have added an excerpt from the top of the csv showing how it is formatted.  There will always be those 14 columns, but rows will vary from several hundred to several thousand, depending of the file being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the pandas module, this code should serve the purpose. Note that `riversDict` is the output dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

riversDict={}

for sheet in os.listdir(path):
    if sheet.endswith(".csv"):
        name=sheet[0:-4]
        dataIn=pd.read_csv(sheet)
        dataIn=dict(dataIn.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'))
        riversDict[name]=dataIn
        print(riversDict)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  It looks like I will need to look into the pandas documentation to see how to slice up those sub-dictionaries to run stats on them.